# Offline Windows Event ID Solution?

Tags: windows, event-log

In my work i have many buildings with no internet , is there a program or an offline database for errors with event ID for Microsoft , so that will save my time for calling my assistants to search for the reason of a unique event Id .

I wish my question is clear for all , and may help others also .

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is called the [Microsoft Knowledge Base](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/SupportResults.aspx?q=kb).

Unfortunately, there is not an offline version.